# Actionscript 3: translating coordinates from object's 3D space to another's?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d

I feel like this has probably been asked/answered here, and if so, I apologize for the bandwidth, but I don't see any explanation.

How does one translate from one object's coordinate space to another in Flash AS3?  I can take a point in an object and translate it to global coordinates using local3DToGlobal() and then to another object's local using globalToLocal3D() -- but is there a direct way?

Thus, if I wanted one object to be able to say to another: 'move your top left corner to my top left corner', even through the two objects are in different z-spaces, rotated 3-dimensionally, etc.

I assume it is in the matrix3D matrix manipulations —

Matrix multiplication?  TransformVector()?  deltaTransformVector()?

I have been poring over the API but would really appreciate a concrete example.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite see what you mean... but if you want to move one `DisplayObject` to another `DisplayObject`'s position, why don't just simply use `local3DToGlobal()` twice, once for each `DisplayObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be [`getRelativeMatrix3D()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Transform.html#getRelativeMatrix3D%28%29), called from the `transform` property of a display object, as in: `transform.getRelativeMatrix3d(root).position`.

> Returns a Matrix3D object, which can transform the space of a
>   specified display object in relation to the current display object's
>   space. You can use the getRelativeMatrix3D() method to move one
>   three-dimensional display object relative to another three-dimensional
>   display object.

From Adobe's [Performing complex 3D transformations](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSA340940C-A537-450c-8069-A4A052A98CAA.html), there is an example using Matrix3D objects for reordering display, in which faces of a box are reordered to ensure that layering of 3D display objects corresponds to the relative depths after rotations have been applied:

```
var faces:Array;

for (var i:uint = 0; i < 6; i++) 
{ 
    faces[i].z = faces[i].child.transform.getRelativeMatrix3D(root).position.z; 
    this.removeChild(faces[i].child); 
} 
faces.sortOn("z", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING); 
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
{ 
    this.addChild(faces[i].child); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm coming back to this after having worked on other parts of the project but this seemed a good bet where I left off.  Would this work well, as well, for determining the x/y position of objects in a z-space in reference to stage coordinates?  What I mean is -- if I have, say, a bunch of balls with varying z-depths, can I set them to appear at specific global x/y coordinates using the above?  I had thought that displayObject.globalToLocal3D would work, but not really, if I use the 'ball' as the displayObject -- the frame of reference then is IN the ball.  But what frame of ref to use?

Comment: Probably - for particle systems, I would focus on a bounding box using that container as a reference for all entities within.